# Http 1.1 500 internal server error on published mvc app but not on local host

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that will send an email like this:

```
<Authorize>
<HttpPost()>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Public Function SubmitIssue(<Bind(Include:="ID,Summary,Description,Comment,Attachment")>
table as iTable, mail as iTable, fileuploader as HttpPostedFileBase)
'send email code
'redirect to view
End Function
```

Then the view contains this:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitIssue","User",FormMethod.Post, New With { .id = "form1", .enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) 

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

'html view page
```

The exact same code and SQL database being used on the server application and the localhost application are being used.  Why is it that I get the Http 1.1 500 internal server error message on the server application?

Is there a difference between the server and the localhost application that prevents it from working properly?  I had it working before on a simpler way but had to add information to it so it is not the server blocking the request.

The application on the server will redirect to the MVC error message page and say:

Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

The localhost application will return a HTTP Result will return 302 and redirect to the correct view, but the published application will HTTP Result will return 500.

Comment: What is the exception getting thrown?

Comment: The default mvc error message page will display saying Error.    An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: So, debug the application and see what exception is getting thrown. Or look at any logging you have. A HTTP 500  could be anything. All that is telling us is you have an internal server error.

Comment: how will i debug my application to find out what exception is being thrown from a published MVC application, I am currently using Fiddler to debug the HTTP Requests but it's not detailed enough either

Comment: Run it locally and debug it. Remotely debug it. OR (Will take longer but would be worth it) look at a logging framework like `Elmah` or `Log4Net`

Comment: It works locally though that's the problem no error occurs then.